# SkyDrive on Windows 8.1 is uploading files INCREDIBLY slowly

Tags: windows-8.1, upload, onedrive

I am currently migrating my file storage onto SkyDrive. I have copied in my Project directory which is where I store my files. The directory is only a few hundred MB's, spans around 50,000 files.

These files have been uploading over the last 2 days, and so far, only about 100MB has been uploaded, and only 4,000 files. When I watch the apps Progress page, it uploads a file in a few seconds, then waits about 5-10 minutes before progressing to the next file, all the while, SkyDrive is using around 20% of my i7 continuously, all the while the Disk and Network usages are at 0, only pulsing when it gets around to actually uploading a file.

Does anyone know why it is being so slow, and any way that I might be able to increase the speed? Anything that can bring my ETA closer than the middle of March would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are there any errors in the Skydrive Store app? I think that's where I found the reason I was having problems.

Comment: while your description does sound excessive, most file transfer operations have a fixed-time overhead while negotiating a connection (etc). For Myriad small files, this can take more time than the actual transfer (per file). In FTP, this would be mitigated in part by increasing the number of concurrent connections to the server.

Comment: @Louis nope, no errors at all

Comment: @horatio that makes sense, but 5-10 mins of handshake? But give the way people now handle their data, wouldn't that be a huge mis-step from MS. Hell, what happened to zipping all these files together and uploading a single one, thats what I do with huge file dumps via FTP. P.S. in this case, although high, its not that excessive, its only about 50 sites and a couple of dozen designs. Adds up super quick

Comment: I meant to say "it sounds excessive even though {overhead etc}". Have you tried disabling "real time virus protection" features (if any)? Without knowing anything about Skydrive It is also plausible that the server is throttling or queuing you on a per-file basis, or you have a "passive/active connect" style problem as in ftp.

Comment: @horatio ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. But disabling virus protection is a great idea! just trying it out now

Comment: @horatio It's really really REALLY hard to tell, but it might be a bit quicker...

Answer (score 0):

OK, it now seems to be operating quicker. I turned off wifi to disable skydrive, then cut everything out the skydrive dir into a temp dir, turned wifi back on, waited for it to do a rebuild from what it had already uploaded and was there, then copied the items back and now, its syncing nice and quick. Not sure if it was from that, or separate else, but it seems to be more a realistic 3 days...

Comment: Wow, now its shot up to by morning